What would be an appropriate way to include the .sty file of a custom package in an answer/post if it is longer than 30000 characters?
Drawing intersecting planes in TikZ is a well-known struggle.
pgfplots cannot draw vertical planes, nor can it layer two intersecting planes correctly.
This seems like it should already have a library or a package or something, but I am not aware of one.
I would like to improve on some answers I contributed, which are based on a custom package I wrote. This package lets me draw the planes in much less syntax, and lets me do a lot of stuff with them.
The problem is that the package now exceeds the 30000 character limit.
What would be an appropriate way to include the .sty file in an answer/post so that I don't violate the character limit.
(with the package, the code can be done in a snippet)

Post the package to CTAN, allow it to be available in TL/MiKTeX, then update the answers to use it.

As I learn and grow, I expect to run into better ways of doing things. A concern I have with posting the package to CTAN is that if I update it, and the syntax is no longer the same, then people won't be able to use it. What would your thoughts be regarding this issue? For instance, I might decide to use keys for more things, instead of parameters. Among other fixes.

If it's really 'alpha' code you could link to a repository (GitHub, GitLab, your own website with a fixed version), or you could upload to CTAN with docs containing a big warning: "THIS IS ALPHA CODE v0.0.0 - USE AT YOUR OWN RISK" - both approaches have merit.

Interesting. I think I will post to GitHub for now, and then maybe when it is more robust and is critiqued by others, I would consider posting to CTAN. Thank you for your time. :-)
